# How to retrieve digits including the separator "."

Tags: bash, sed

I am using grep to get a string like this: `ANS_LENGTH=266.50` then I use sed to only get the digits: 266.50

This is my full command: `grep --text 'ANS_LENGTH=' log.txt | sed -e 's/[^[[:digit:]]]*//g'`

The result is : 26650

How can this line be changed so the result still shows the separator: 266.50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `grep` if you are going to use `sed`. Just use `sed'` `//` to match the lines you need to print.

```
sed -n '/ANS_LENGTH/s/[^=]*=\(.*\)/\1/p' log.txt
```

- `-n` will suppress printing of lines that do not match `/ANS_LENGTH/`
- Using captured group we print the value next to `=` sign.
- `p` flag at the end allows to print the lines that matches our `//`.

If your `grep` happens to support `-P` option then you can do:

```
grep -oP '(?<=ANS_LENGTH=).*' log.txt
```

- `(?<=...)` is a look-behind construct that allows us to match the lines you need. This requires the `-P` option
- `-o` allows us to print only the value part.

Comment: Silly me. Thanks looks much better than with the grep

Comment: @Coenster You can also use my weapon of choice, `awk`. Do `awk -F'=' '/ANS_LENGTH/{print $2}' log.txt`

Comment: Also, cut ? If you know that number is expected after a "=" .

Answer (score 1):

You need to match a literal dot as well as the digits.

Try `sed -e 's/[^[[:digit:]\.]]*//g'`

The dot will match any single character. Escaping it with the backslash will match only a literal dot.

Comment: `[^[:digit:].]` and not [[ ]] aroutn digit, the dot should normaly not be escaped into []

Answer (score 0):

Here is some `awk` example:

```
cat file:
some data ANS_LENGTH=266.50 other=22
not mye data=43
```

`gnu awk` (due to RS)

```
awk '/ANS_LENGTH/ {f=NR} f&&NR-1==f' RS="[ =]" file
266.50
```

```
awk '/ANS_LENGTH/ {getline;print}' RS="[ =]" file
266.50
```

Plain `awk`

```
awk -F"[ =]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="ANS_LENGTH") print $(i+1)}' file
266.50
```

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~"ANS_LENGTH") {split($i,a,"=");print a[2]}}' file
266.50
```